# React dynamically using sub-components with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdbootstrap, mdbreact

Maybe there is a better way, but I try to make my React components as reusable as possible. So I am using a bootstrap Card and inside this Card I wanna place different components from outside (with props) dynamically. Without props it works fine. But with props I got an error message "Error: Cannot find module '../../pages/Dummy'".

This works perfect:

```
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
import { MDBCard, MDBCardBody } from "mdbreact";

const Area = (props) => {

    const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/Dummy'));

    return (
            <MDBCard className="text-center">
                <MDBCardBody>
                    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                        <OtherComponent/>
                    </Suspense>
                </MDBCardBody>
            </MDBCard>
    );
};

export default Area;
```

This doesn't work:

```
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
import { MDBCard, MDBCardBody } from "mdbreact";

const Area = (props) => {

    const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import(props.compName));

    return (
            <MDBCard className="text-center">
                <MDBCardBody>
                    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                        <OtherComponent/>
                    </Suspense>
                </MDBCardBody>
            </MDBCard>
    );
};

export default Area;
```

Call from outside:

```
<Area compName='../../pages/Dummy'/>
```

It's like I cannot lazy-load with props. Very strange.

Btw. I don't need to use lazy-loading if there is an easier way to use sub-components dynamically. I just thought this is the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options:

The first one uses 'slots,' which you can read about in the React docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment), or an article [here](https://daveceddia.com/pluggable-slots-in-react-components/).

```js
const DummyOne = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/DummyOne');
const DummyTwo = React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/DummyTwo');

const Area = ({ comp }) => {
  return (
    <MDBCard className="text-center">
      <MDBCardBody>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          {comp}
        </Suspense>
      </MDBCardBody>
    </MDBCard>
  );
}

// You dynamically pass the component itself into 'Area'
<Area comp={<DummyOne />} />
```

The second option is closer to what you have:

```js
const Area = ({ compName }) => {
  const components = {
    DummyOne: React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/DummyOne'),
    DummyTwo: React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/DummyTwo'),
  }

  const DynamicComponent = components[compName];

  return (
    <MDBCard className="text-center">
      <MDBCardBody>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <DynamicComponent />
        </Suspense>
      </MDBCardBody>
    </MDBCard>
  );
}

// You dynamically pass the component name to 'Area' as a string
<Area compName="DummyOne" />
```